# Reading from a csv file and processing it in .net

Tags: c#, .net, csv, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a csv file with 2 rows in it.

```
 A,1
 B,2
```

I want to read this file in the format and convert it to the following format:

```
Name : A, ID: 1
Name : B, ID: 2
```

I am using the following .net api

```
using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"Data.csv")) // mind the encoding - UTF8
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
            {
                parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true; // if you want
                parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] line = parser.ReadFields();

                    List<string> li = line.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();


                }
            }
```

In the li variable , I am able to get the individual elements after splitting for eg: A   1, but I am not getting how to add the key attribute to it, to make Name : A, ID : 1

Edit :

I need it in a list format finally as it is easy to separate the entities based on that
eg:

```
List{
    List1 = Name : A,ID:1
    List2 = Name : B,ID:2
}
```

Comment: You should consider using [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library for reading and processing CSV files.

Comment: What does parser.`ReadFields();` returns when (for example) you parse the first line?

Comment: So what is the advantage of `TextFieldParser` class if it gives you the exact result of a `StreamReader.ReadLine()`?

Comment: This function ReadFields();  will give output as A,1. Reading the data is not the problem here , its only post processing of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create struct for that :

```
struct ValuePair
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }        

    public ValuePair(string name, string id) : this()
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name : " + Name + ", Id : " + Id;
    }
}
```

And in your code you can use it:

```
List<ValuePair> data = new List<ValuePair>();
for(int i = 0; i < li.Count; i += 2) 
   data.Add(new ValuePair(li[i], li[i + 1]));
```

then use `data[i].ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the output string yourself ...

```
StringBuilder sb = newStringBuilder();
using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"Data.csv")) // mind the encoding - UTF8
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
        {
            parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true; // if you want
            parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] line = parser.ReadFields();

                List<string> li = line.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();

                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Name: {0}, ID: {1}", li[0],li[1]));

            }
        }
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

---

Note that you probably want to delimit the (text) values with `""` (assuming you want to read back from your new format), and that you will also need to decide on a suitable scheme for escaping `"` when it appears in the value.
A common way to do this is replacing each `"` in a value with `""`.

Eg
    FirstValue,1
    Sec"ond"Value",2

would map to

```
Name: "FirstValue", ID:1
Name: "Sec""ond""Value", ID:2
```

If you don't do this then reading back from your new format may be indeterminant.